# How to reset camera altitude in Google earth

Tags: google-maps, google-earth-plugin

I want to reset the camera position to a much higher position or lesser zoom.

I am looking at the code here:

http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/drive-simulator/index.html

I think it should be done using DS_simulator object, but am not able to find out how.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DDSimulator is just the name of the class in that example, it is not part of the Google Earth Api.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Camera` or `LookAt` to achieve this. Zooming in and out is controlled by the `range` attribute for a `LookAt`, and the `altitude` attribute for a `Camera`.

Here is a quick example of setting the `range` using a `lookat`.

```
// Get the current view.
var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

// Zoom out to twice the current range.
lookAt.setRange(lookAt.getRange() * 2.0);

// Update the view in Google Earth.
ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);
```

See this document for more information on controling the view using these two objects.
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/camera_control

Also, you can play with a working example here.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=earth#move_camera

Comment: Do you know default range values being used by Google Earth desktop application?

Comment: What do you mean by default range values? In what context?

Comment: I meant the default values that Google Earth desktop version uses. The default zoom level (range value) that it uses so that whenever we search for a specific city or country, it neither zooms too close the city nor too far away from city rather it sets its zoom level to such a value that shows the whole map of the city. I want to know those values so that I can set my camera zoom level to that default values so that my JS plugin also works like traditional desktop version GE

Comment: The view bounds depend on the size (geographic area) of the thing you are searching for - search for "USA" vs "Statue of liberty" - there is no such thing as a "default range". For a rough guide why not simply search for things and note the range?  Also - you should ask your own questions in the proper manner, not in the comments to an answer to someone elses question...